# Samples with the same means but different variance

Tags: probability

Is there a way to determine how probable it is that two samples with the same means but different variance comes from the same population?

For instance, if one sample contains 100 5's, and one sample contains 50 1's and 50 9's it is unlikly that they come from the same population. How unlikly?

Comment: In trying to understand this, I realized that in most cases it's extremely unlikely that two *random* samples of the same population would actually have the same means. Do you really want us to assume the means are the same? Or are you actually trying to compare two samples based on both their means and their variances?

Comment: Both cases are actually interesting (even though one is very improbable)

Comment: Your examples include many observations having identical values. Is that property of the samples important, or would you really be considering continuously distributed variables, with the identical values in your examples provided just to make your question clearer?

Comment: That property is not important, I just used it to make my question clearer.

Comment: Anyone out there who can help me with this?

Comment: There is the F-test if you are willing to assume normal populations for your two samples.

Answer (score 2):

The two-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test has the null hypothesis that the two samples come from the same distribution. Check The Wikipedia entry on the KS test for details and a table of critical values.

Answer (score 0):

See the excellent [answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/251490/permutation-test-for-two-distributions-with-the-same-mean-but-unequal-variance/) to the question "Permutation test for two distributions with the same mean but unequal variance".  You want to use the `mood_test()` or the `ansari_test()` in R.