# Permutation test for two distributions with the same mean but unequal variance

Tags: kruskal-wallis-test, permutation-test

I am using the `coin` package in R.  For two distributions with the same mean but different variance, the test is unable to reject the null hypothesis that the two distributions are the same.

```
numSamples <- 100
numSimulations <- 100000
df1 <- data.frame(y=rnorm(numSamples, mean=0), label='A')
df2 <- data.frame(y=rnorm(numSamples, mean=0, sd=10), label='B')
df <- rbind(df1, df2)

kruskal_test(y ~ as.factor(label), 
             distribution=approximate(B=numSimulations-1),
             data=df)

    Approximative Kruskal-Wallis Test

data:  y by as.factor(label) (A, B)
chi-squared = 0.82617, p-value = 0.3658
```

I tried both the Fisher-Pitman `oneway_test()` and the Kruskal-Wallis test `kruskal_test()`.

Are there non-parametric tests that can tell whether two sets of data have the same variance or not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both `oneway_test()` and `kruskal_test()` are tests for differences in the *mean* in $k$ samples (with $k$ potentially $> 2$). The former corresponds to a parametric ANOVA whereas the latter is a rank-based test (also of ANOVA-type).

For assessing differences in *scale/variance*, various other choices of tests are available: both classical and rank-based. Two prominent examples are the Mood test and the Ansari-Bradley test which are easily available with convenience interfaces in `coin`. And these lead to clearly significant results:

```
mood_test(y ~ as.factor(label),
  distribution = approximate(B = numSimulations - 1), data = df)
##  Approximative Two-Sample Mood Test
## 
## data:  y by as.factor(label) (A, B)
## Z = -10.649, p-value < 2.2e-16
## alternative hypothesis: true ratio of scales is not equal to 1
ansari_test(y ~ as.factor(label),
  distribution = approximate(B = numSimulations - 1), data = df)
##  Approximative Two-Sample Ansari-Bradley Test
## 
## data:  y by as.factor(label) (A, B)
## Z = 10.702, p-value < 2.2e-16
## alternative hypothesis: true ratio of scales is not equal to 1
```

But in `coin` there are also further tests for scale differences and you can easily set up new custom tests on the fly. See the four `coin` package vignettes for more details, e.g., starting with `vignette("coin", package = "coin")`.

Comment: For bivariate distributions, I could not get the tests such as `mood_test(mood_test(y1 + y2 ~ as.factor(label), ...)` to run.  I get an error ``‘y1’‘y2’ is not a numeric variable``.  The only one that works for me is `independence_test(y1 + y2 ~ as.factor(label), ...)`.

Comment: The _Mood test_ refers to a univariate numeric response so that is what `mood_test()` checks for. You can easily generalize this to bivariate responses in `coin` by applying the Mood transformation to each of the responses and then computing a max-type (default) or quadratic-type test statistic. For example, set up a trafo: `mtrafo <- function(data) trafo(data, numeric_trafo = function(y) mood_trafo(y, ties.method = "mid-ranks"))`. And then apply it via: `independence_test(y1 + y2 ~ label, data = df, ytrafo = mtrafo)`. It would be _a Mood-type test_ but not _the Mood test_, though.

Comment: Oh, and `?mood_test` lists several other tests for scale alternatives. And `vignette("LegoCondInf", package = "coin")` explains the _Lego toolbox_ that `coin` provides and how you can plug and play with new test statistics on the fly.

Comment: Is there a test that will determine whether two multivariate distributions have the same covariance matrix $\Sigma$?  One use case is we have $y_1, y_2 \sim \mathcal{N}(0, 1)$ but the correlation $\text{corr}(y_1, y_2) = \rho$ might vary.

Comment: That essentially corresponds to checking whether `(y1 - mean(y1))/sd(y1) * (y2 - mean(y2))/sd(y2) ~ label` has a location shift.

Comment: I don't think so, because in my example, `mean(y1) = mean(y2) = 0` and `sd(y1) = sd(y2) = 1`, but `rho` can be of any value in $[0, 1]$.  Maybe I can compute `corr(y1, y2)` along with the confidence interval.

Comment: Please create a new question for this and I'll post an explanation with a code example.

Comment: I created a new [question](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/252179/permutation-test-for-two-multivariate-distributions-with-the-same-mean-variance) per your suggestion.